# Преобразование списка строк в словарь

Tags: python, dict

Имеется список вида:

```
['object1 Atr1 Atr2 Atr3', 'object2 Atr1 Atr2', 'object3 Atr1', 'object4 Atr1 Atr2 Atr3 Atr4']
```

В котором сохранены строки с описанием некоторого объекта. С начала строки до первого пробела - имя объекта, и далее через пробел, список его атрибутов. Aтрибутов может быть произвольное количество, разделенных также пробелом. Данный список мне необходимо преобразовать в словарь вида:

```
{'object1': ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3'], 'object2': ['Atr1', 'Atr2'], 'object3': ['Atr1'], 'object4': ['Atr1', 'Atr2']}
```

Решаю задачу таким образом:

```
data = ["object1 Atr1 Atr2 Atr3", "object2 Atr1 Atr2", "object3 Atr1", "object4 Atr1 Atr2 Atr3 Atr4", "object4 Atr1 Atr2"]

for i in range(len(data)): # каждую строку в списке преобразую в отдельный список
    data[i] = list(map(str, data[i].split(' ')))

my_dict= {}
for i in range(len(data)): # записываю в качестве ключа первый элемент каждого списка и остальное в отдельный список
    my_dict[data[i][0]] = list(data[i][1:])
```

Чисто технически мой код работает, но понимаю, что наворотил велосипед и это можно сделать элегантнее.

Подскажите, как можно улучшить?

Answer (score 5):

исходные данные:

```
data = [
    'object1 Atr1 Atr2 Atr3', 
    'object2 Atr1 Atr2', 
    'object3 Atr1', 
    'object4 Atr1 Atr2 Atr3 Atr4'
]
```

используем [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
res = {s.split()[0]:s.split()[1:] for s in data}
```

или обычный цикл (в данном случае `s.split()` вызывается только один раз):

```
res = {}

for s in data:
    tmp = s.split()
    res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1:]
```

[для Python 3.8+ можно использовать `walrus operator`](https://repl.it/@maxu777/walrusoperator):

```
res = {tmp[0]:tmp[1:]  for s in data if (tmp := s.split())}
#   NOTE:  ---------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

результат:

```
In [81]: res
Out[81]:
{'object1': ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3'],
 'object2': ['Atr1', 'Atr2'],
 'object3': ['Atr1'],
 'object4': ['Atr1', 'Atr2', 'Atr3', 'Atr4']}
```

Comment: Чтобы split только один раз вызывался на каждый элемент, можно так сделать: `dict((lambda k, *v: (k, list(v)))(*s.split()) for s in data)` - но это довольно извращенно и нечитаемо получается

Comment: @insolor, я тоже пробовал что-то похожее написать, но в итоге решил отказаться из-за не очень понятного кода

Comment: @insolor, для Python 3.8+ можно использовать `walrus operator` ;)

Comment: Неплохо бы пример с этим операторм, я не представляю как это сделать

Comment: @insolor, добавил в ответ